# Bootstrap vue datepicker display UTC

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, timezone, bootstrap-vue

I'm using the `b-form-datepicker` control from [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker#form-datepicker). I want to initialize the control with the date based on the current UTC time not the browser's local time.

So if it's `July 17, 2020 9:00 PM` in Central time (currently UCT-5), the date given in the calendar should say `July 18, 2020` because that corresponds to `July 18, 1:00 AM`. Is this possible?

I *could* do this:

```
const today = new Date();
const d = new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000 * today.getTimezoneOffset()))
```

Even though the resulting `Date` object is not the correct time, it works works because the calendar only shows the date part and not the time. I'm hoping there is a better solution.

I'm initializing the control's `v-model` like this:

```
<template>
    ...
    <b-form-datepicker
        v-model="myDate"
        :date-format-options="{ weekday: 'short', month: 'long' }"
    ></b-form-datepicker>
    ...
</template>

<script>
    ...
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                myDate: new Date()
            }
         }
    ...
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You mean you want the conversion to the value of the v-model ?

Comment: @Raffobaffo Yes, that's correct.

Comment: And when you want the conversion to be made? To explain myself better: are you retrieving the v-model from somewhere and showing it in the date picker, so you need the conversion from UTC to localtime?

Comment: @Raffobaffo I'll update the post but basically I just want the date picker to initialize to the current UTC date when the user first opens the page, not the browser local date. I'm not pulling a particular time from a database or anything.

Comment: Did the answer helped you? I'm doing a PR request to add this functionality. Please let me know

Comment: @Raffobaffo Yes, thank. I didn't realize you could set the value to a string. Or rather I tried but I must have used the wrong date format because it didn't work. Anyway, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for [DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), toISOString always return UTC 0. So you can instantiate your date in that way. I tried an it works in my timezone. Vue-date-picker takes the string and generate the object itself, with the passed timezone Z.

```
<template>
    ...
    <b-form-datepicker
        v-model="myDate"
        :date-format-options="{ weekday: 'short', month: 'long' }"
    ></b-form-datepicker>
    ...
</template>

<script>
    ...
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                myDate: new Date().toISOString()
            }
         }
    ...
    }
</script>
```